# Why marker rotation method is not available in my Android Google Map

Tags: android

I use Google Map API V2 for my Android app. According to the developer guide, I should be able to rotate the marker. But now I don't have rotation method in my GoogleMap object's MarkerOptions.
All methods available at MarkerOptions() are as shown in the attached image.
Why is it missing in my GoogleMap object?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082629/maps-v2-how-to-rotate-marker-where-is-rotation-option. i guess that is what you want?

Comment: `map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                                     .title(getString(title))
                                     .snippet(getString(snippet))
                                     .flat(flat).rotation(rotation))` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, but as you see in the attached image, I don't have .flat and .rotation methods.

Comment: @Raghunandan I am trying the approach as discussed in the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274920/arrow-mark-over-polyline-in-android-google-route-map

Comment: that is not for map object as you see it is for markeroptions

Comment: Mine is also same, right? map.addMarker(0.().etc

Comment: Sorry you are right they are for marker options. I don't have rotation method at marker options

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40090/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-batuman)

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution. My Google Play Services should be updated to Rev12

Comment: that link i posted also says the same thing. yes you need rev 12 and it works i tried it and i was confused bcoz the docs says it has the method and i was thinking why it won't work for oyu