# Can't rotate marker using google maps v.2

Tags: android, google-maps

The goal is to make marker rotate towards the next coordinate point. Here is the method to get the angle:

```
private double computeAngleBetween(LatLng from, LatLng to) {
    double fromLat = from.latitude;
    double fromLng = from.longitude;
    double toLat = to.latitude;
    double toLng = to.longitude;
    double dLat = fromLat - toLat;
    double dLng = fromLng - toLng;
    return 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
            cos(fromLat) * cos(toLat) * pow(sin(dLng / 2), 2)));
}
```

And here is the code, where I create a Marker:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //Unnecessary code is deleted
    float bearing = (float)computeAngleBetween(theRoute.get(0),theRoute.get(1));

    Marker theAirplane = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(start)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airplane))
            .flat(true)
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .rotation(bearing)
            .draggable(true));
    theAirplane.setRotation(bearing);

    movePlane(theAirplane, theRoute.size()-1);

}
```

So, I cannot figure out what is the problem. Everything seems to be alright, but nothing works, can you help me please?

Comment: try to convert it to degrees, like `Math.toDegrees(radians)`

Answer (score 0):

You may use '*setRotation(float rotation)*' to set the rotation of the marker. The axis of rotation is perpendicular to the marker. A rotation of 0 corresponds to the default position of the marker.

Make sure that you have the latest Play Services SDK attached to your project. You need to download r12 from the SDK Manager then attach that library project to your project.

Here is a sample project demostrate how to use 'setRotation': https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/FlatMarkers

Here's where I found my answer: [Maps V2 how to rotate Marker - where is rotation option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082629/maps-v2-how-to-rotate-marker-where-is-rotation-option)